# Github Issues as Tasks in Mylyn ( Push task works, pull issues(Tasks) doesn't )

Tags: eclipse, github, task, issue-tracking, mylyn

So I've recently started using Mylyn at my company, love it personally and works great with Jira.  However now I'm trying to get it working on Github for personal projects that I work on with several other people.

I'm using Eclipse Juno with the Github connector and added the repository information.  When I go create a task, it correctly does so and does pull the tags that I have configured correctly, so I know it has good connectivity both ways.  When I save the task in Mylyn it will show up on Github just fine.

The problem is, I need access to issues that others create on Github, but when I create a Query in Mylyn and name it ( Say "All Bugs" ), then choose the bug labels and hit finish it shows the query in the Task view, however it is empty and never retrieves the list of Issues from Github.  I know their there, it's just not showing them in Mylyn, and Mylyn isn't throwing any errors.

I've also tried a Query with all the above and "Mention" field with my name( just in case the blank fields were messing with the query ) however that didn't work either.

One thing to note, I'm using this on a Private repo, but doing searching( and as evidence that I can fetch labels and push issues ) I don't think private Vs public repos are an issue here.

Really hope someone can lend a hand.  Thanks

Answer (score 1):

@TheKojuEffect answered this one for me here:

[Why Mylyn is not getting issues from GitHub?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16328660/why-mylyn-is-not-getting-issues-from-github)

Basically, if you select more than one label in your query in Eclipse, the query will only pull the issues with ALL of those labels (Logical AND, as opposed to the OR that I was expecting).  Create a query for each of the issue labels you'd like to see.

Answer (score 0):

The best approach to this is to open a bug report against Github connector for Mylyn.